# Javascript menu opens all sub-menus at once

Tags: javascript, arrays, menu

Trying to make a simple vanilla js dropdown menu. I want to use vanilla js to practice and am absolutely stuck on this. 
The problem is that when I click on a link with dropdown, all dropdowns open.
Using forEach but not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
let itemsHasDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.has_children');
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');


    //looping through all buttons with dropdowns
    itemsHasDropdowns.forEach(function(singleItemHasDropdowns){
       //adding click event to each btn
       singleItemHasDropdowns.addEventListener('click', function(){
      //looping through each dropdown
       dropdowns.forEach(function(dropdown) {
       //adding class that opens dropdowns
       dropdown.classList.add('open');

    });
  });
});
```

https://codepen.io/YourMuseAnya/pen/XWXXPYa

NOTE:
I HAVE looked at other questions on SO. Everyone seems to be using jquery , not vanilla JS. YouTube & Google search didn't help either.

I don't need someone to write the whole thing for me, just push me to the right direction if you can.
Thanks

EDIT: 
Tried doing this but now only the last dropdown opens...

```
let theParentOfDropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.has_children');
let dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown');
let singleDropdown = '';


dropdowns.forEach(function(dropdown){
    singleDropdown = dropdown;
});


theParentOfDropdowns.forEach(function(singleItemHasDropdowns){
  singleItemHasDropdowns.addEventListener('click', openDropdown, false);
});

function openDropdown(e) {
   if(e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
     let clickedItem = e.target.tagName;
      console.log(clickedItem);
      singleDropdown.classList.add('open');
     }
   e.stopPropagation();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is you attaching a click on each dropdown elements. When you click, the event is call and then move throught each ".dropdown" class and  add the class open.

Comment: Alright, I see. Thank you! Appreciate your advice